# Machine readable list of files in rar archive

Tags: linux, command-line, rar, parsing

I need a way to get a **parsable list** of all files in a .rar archive **without extracting** them, in bash or python.

What I've tried:

`rar l *.rar
7z l -slt *.rar`

I've also looked at `patool` in python, but it seems to be just a thin wrapper over `rar`.

I want the equivalent of `tar -tvf`. One file name per line, no extra details. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `rar -?`: `l[t[a],b]     List archive contents [technical[all], bare]`

```
rar lb *.rar
```

Comment: Thanks! funny, my rar help file didn't have this info, but the command works... I just have:

l[t]   List content of archive [technical].

Comment: Hmmm interesting my output is from RAR 5.01 on windows. Would you mind marking my answer as the solution? :)

Comment: I'm still on Ubuntu 14.04 with rar 4.20, but this page http://ss64.com/bash/rar.html also misses this info. Perhaps I should file a bug somewhere.

(there was a 8 minute timeout before I was able to accept the answer)

Comment: Might be a good idea. But I wouldn't know where, sorry. Maybe the maintainer for the Ubuntu Package? Don't worry, it was just meant as a reminder and you seemed like a nice person.

Comment: I actually filed a bug on the Ubuntu package, it's here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rar/+bug/1626056

Comment: In other versions, `rar vb` or `unrar vb` should work.